# Gitlab pass values from child pipeline to parent pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, parent-child, pipeline

I have a monorepo which each package should be build as a docker. and when all changed package dockerized I want to deploy then using helmfile

I created a trigger job for each package that trigger a child pipeline.

I am looking for a way to get values that generated in child pipeline like docker tag or chart version in the parent pipeline.

I need those values to the deploy phase that is happened after all child pipeline finish.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
---
trigger-package-a:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab/ci/packages/package-gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
   - changes:
      - "packages/package-a/**/*"
  variables:
    PACKAGE: package-a

trigger-package-b:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab/ci/packages/package-gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - changes:
      - "packages/package-b/**/*"
  variables:
    PACKAGE: package-b

done_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "echo DONE"
    - "cat config.json"
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
```

**package-gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - bootstrap
  - validate

cache:
  key: "${PACKAGE}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  paths:
    - packages/${PACKAGE}/node_modules/
  policy: pull

install-package:
  stage: bootstrap
  script:
    - echo ${PACKAGE}}
    - echo '{"package":${PACKAGE}}' > config.json
    - "cd packages/${PACKAGE}/"
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - config.json
  cache:
    key: "${PACKAGE}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
    paths:
     - packages/${PACKAGE}/node_modules/
    policy: pull-push

lint-package:
  script:
   - yarn lint
  stage: validate
  needs: [install-package]
  before_script:
   - "cd packages/${PACKAGE}/"
```

Comment: you cannot pass variables from child to parent. You will have to pass the values using a new trigger.

Comment: As @linuxUser123 said: You cannot pass variables from child to parent. But you could get artifacts from child-pipelines with GitLab-API (bridge jobs -> downstream pipelines -> specific jobs).

Comment: Somehow I was able to use cache to access files written in the child pipeline from the parent pipeline (using the same cache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get values and files only by get Artifacts via GitLab CI API

previous - create token for your User Gitlab and
create var GITLAB_USER_TOKEN

[image]

```
done_job:
  image: nexus/docker-images/ansible:2.9.24-9
  stage: done_job
  script:
    - yum install -y unzip 
    - >
        export CI_CHILD_PIPELINE_ID=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_USER_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_ID/bridges" | jq ".[].downstream_pipeline.id")
    - echo $CI_CHILD_PIPELINE_ID
    - >
        export CI_CHILD_JOB_ID=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_USER_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_CHILD_PIPELINE_ID/jobs" | jq '.[].id')
    - echo $CI_CHILD_JOB_ID 
    - 'curl --output artifacts.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_USER_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/$CI_CHILD_JOB_ID/artifacts"'
    - unzip artifacts.zip
    - "echo DONE"
    - "cat config.json"
    - rm -rf artifacts.tar
```

Comment: Nice trick, thanks! But in case if you have to download huge directory as a zip file, you should also send "-L" parameter to curl command.

Comment: if you use proxy_server - add -L

Answer (score 0):

I am chiming in here as I found a way to do this with ease.

create a cache with a common key (like $CI_COMMIT_SHA) and place it in default, so that all jobs in the pipeline use it. Then add an environment directory to the cache.
This will cache any files added to the env/ directory

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  paths:
    - .env/*.env
```

To use the cache you will need to write to a .env file within the .env/ directory with a key-value entry and then have it read later

```
example.write.to.cache:
  script:
    - echo "EXAMPLE_VAR="EXAMPLE_VALUE" >> .env/${CI_COMMIT_SHA}-${CI_JOB_NAME}.env
```

Next you want to have a Job that will take all the files within the .env/ directory and combine them into a single key-value file. As well as adding the newly created file as a dotenv artifact.

```
source.env.vars.from.cache:
  stage: build
    script:
      - cat .env/*.env >> ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}.env
      - cat ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}.env
    artifacts:
      reports:
        dotenv: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}.env
```

This will create a .env cache for everything to use across all jobs and pipelines parent->child and child->parent with one catch that order of operation matters.

*NOTE: If 2 jobs have the cache open and make writes to it then the last one to write to it will overwrite the other.*

To consume the variables that are defined within your cache you must have a "needs" statement that points to the job that archived the cache.

```
print.cache.varible:
  script:
    - echo "EXAMPLE_VAR=${EXAMPLE_VAR}"
  needs:
    - job: source.env.vars.from.cache
```

Full Example:
In this example we create 2 child pipelines, write a variable into the cache within the first and then read it from the second. You could also read the variable from the parent if you were to run the source.env.vars.from.cache job AFTER the first service runs and BEFORE the consuming job.

*NOTE: artifact vars WILL override default and Job level variables.*

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
service_1:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: ".service_1.yml"
    strategy: depend

service_2:
  stage: build
  needs:
    - job: service_1 # This will force service_2 to wait for service_1 to complete
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: ".service_2.yml"
    strategy: depend
```

**.service_1.yml**

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  paths:
    - .env/*.env

write.to.cache:
      script:
        - echo "SERVICE_1_VAR="ABCD-1234" >> .env/${CI_COMMIT_SHA}-${CI_JOB_NAME}.env
```

**.service_2.yml**

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  paths:
    - .env/*.env

source.env.vars.from.cache:
  stage: .pre
    script:
      - cat .env/*.env >> ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}.env
      - cat ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}.env
    artifacts:
      reports:
        dotenv: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}.env

print.cache.varible:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "SERVICE_1_VAR=${SERVICE_1_VAR}"
  needs:
    - job: source.env.vars.from.cache
```

*This took me longer than I care to admit to come up with and as I did not see this solution anywhere I figured I would post it.*